# Creating new dataframes based on a existing dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, merge, google-colaboratory

I have two dataframes  that completes each other but I need to create a third taking data from both dataframes. But each data needs to match with with the right information.

So df1 looks like this

```
Name   Team   
John    A
Nathan  B
Eric    C
```

Df2 looks like this

```
Date         Name    Status   
 01/01/2022   John    Active
 02/01/2022   John    Active
 03/01/2022   John    Active
 01/01/2022  Nathan  Active
 02/01/2022  Nathan  Active
 03/01/2022 Eric    Deactivated 
 04/01/2022 Eric    Active
```

I need my python code to look at both dfs see that the names are equal to each other and bring the correct team so df3 should look like this

```
Date         Name    Status  team 
 01/01/2022   John    Active    A
 02/01/2022   John    Active    A
 03/01/2022   John    Active    A
 01/01/2022  Nathan   Active     B
 02/01/2022  Nathan   Active     B
 03/01/2022  Eric     Deactivated C
 04/01/2022  Eric     Active      C
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `df2.merge(df1, on='Name')`. [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: It’s not working it gives different  teams for each name. So John is in team A but when I merge John is in team B

Comment: Try @MYousefi's answer but with `how="left"`: `df2.merge(df1, how="left", on="Name")

Comment: That's odd. The example above works exactly as expected.

Comment: @Isaac Are there possibly any duplicate names?

Comment: It’s usually one status per day per person so there will be duplicate names. When I try to merge the teams don’t line up correctly for some of the names.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why do the outputs of those attempts not work? Please edit your post to contain these details.

Comment: So i tried merge just like @MYousefi  said and i tried np.where by passing the condition if the names are equal them put the correct team with it but none of these are working. When I use merge a lot of the names comes up with the wrong teams. What I was thinking was to create kind like a Vlookup in excell where it will look at the data set see that the names match and bring the correct team everytime there is a new entry into the log sheet.

Comment: I got it guys i went back and looked ate the dataset and noticed that the names of the teams were not lining up correctly so when i merged the two the names didnt line up but after i corrected the merge worked fine!!!! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two DataFrame objects:

```
DF1
     Name Team
0    John    A
1  Nathan    B
2    Eric    C
```

```
DF2
        Date    Name       Status
0 2022-01-01    John       Active
1 2022-02-01    John       Active
2 2022-03-01    John       Active
3 2022-01-01  Nathan       Active
4 2022-02-01  Nathan       Active
5 2022-03-01    Eric  Deactivated
6 2022-04-01    Eric       Active
```

Combining them with merge we get:

```
DF2.merge(DF1, how='inner', on='Name')
```

```
        Date    Name       Status Team
0 2022-01-01    John       Active    A
1 2022-02-01    John       Active    A
2 2022-03-01    John       Active    A
3 2022-01-01  Nathan       Active    B
4 2022-02-01  Nathan       Active    B
5 2022-03-01    Eric  Deactivated    C
6 2022-04-01    Eric       Active    C
```

For the given example an `inner` merge is sufficient.

Comment: I will try this again but I don’t know if it will work.

Comment: I tried it but some of the teams are not lining up  with the correct name.